# Passing Parent Method to Child in Svelte

Tags: svelte

As the title suggests, I am trying to pass a method from a parent component to a child component.

For example,

*App.html*

```html
<div>
  <TodoItem
     done={todo.done}
     toggle={toggle}
  />
</div>
<script>
 import TodoItem from './TodoItem.html';
 export default {
   components: {
     TodoItem,
   },
   methods: {
     toggle(index) {
       console.log(index);
     },
   },
 };
</script>
```

*TodoItem.html*

```html
<div>
  <button on:click="toggle(0)"></button>
</div>
<script>
 export default {
   methods: {
     toggle(index) {
       // a guess. this works if you pass in console.log
       this.options.data.toggle(index)
     },
   },
 };
</script>
```

The desired functionality is that TodoItem calls the parent's method with its data.

This example breaks, the console logs `TypeError: this.options.data.toggle is not a function`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's *possible* to pass methods down to child components, but it's a little awkward. A more idiomatic approach is to fire an event from the child component and listen for that event from the parent component:

*App.html*

```html
<div>
  <TodoItem
    {todo}
    on:toggle="toggle(todo)"
  />
</div>
<script>
  import TodoItem from './TodoItem.html';
  export default {
    components: {
      TodoItem,
    },
    methods: {
      toggle(todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done;
        const { todos } = this.get();
        this.set({ todos });
     }
   }
 };
</script>
```

*TodoItem.html*

```html
<div>
  <button on:click="fire('toggle')">{todo.description}</button>
</div>
```

If you need to pass an event up through multiple levels of components you can just refire the event...

```html
<TodoItem on:toggle="fire('toggle', event)">...</TodoItem>
```

...but there's a shorthand for doing so that means the same thing:

```
<TodoItem on:toggle>...</TodoItem>
```

Comment: What if the child is not a component but a simple `<button>`?

Comment: This is easier in Svelte 3 as Ujjwal Kumar Gupta pointed out. Maybe it's worth updating this answer with the Svelte 3 example along the Svelte 2 version since this has already been accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 30):

Seems like "fire" was part of svelte v2 but in svelte v3 it's changed with `createEventDispatcher`

e.g -

child.svelte

```html
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function sayHello() {
        dispatch('message', {
            text: 'Hello!'
        });
    }
</script>

<button on:click={sayHello}>
    Click to say hello
</button>
```

parent.svelte

```html
<script>
    import Inner from './child.svelte';

    function handleMessage(event) {
        alert(event.detail.text);
    }
</script>

<Inner on:message={handleMessage}/>
```

for more info - please visit : https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

From the [SOURCE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrkBrxJDbn8)

> Useful when the component can't live without a parent, and the parent can't live without the component

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte'
    
    const handleSubmit = value => {
        console.log(value)
    }
</script>

<Child {handleSubmit}/>
```

Child.svelte

```
<script>
    export let handleSubmit
    let value = ''
    
    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        handleSubmit(value)
    }
</script>

<form on:submit={onSubmit}>
    <input type="text" bind:value/>
</form>
```

Another solution is to use context

> Useful when all the children and grandchildren components may or may not call the function. The function allows all children and grandchildren components to update the state / make changes to the common parent component.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/08b33929050745f58480621ecf6d27e9?version=3.45.0)

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { getContext, setContext } from 'svelte';
    import Child1 from './Child1.svelte';
    import Child2 from './Child2.svelte';
    
    let counter = 10;
    
    setContext('counter', { increment, decrement });
    
    function increment(delta) {
        counter += delta;
    }
    function decrement(delta) {
        counter -= delta;
    }
</script>

<Child1 />
<Child2 />

<button on:click={() => { increment(10); }}>
    Increment x10
</button>

<div>{counter}</div>
```

Child1.svelte

```
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    
    const { increment } = getContext('counter');
</script>

<button on:click={() => increment(1)}>Increment</button>
```

Child2.svelte

```
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    
    const { decrement } = getContext('counter');
</script>

<button on:click={() => decrement(1)}>Decrement</button>
```

Comment: By using the `| preventDefault` modifier it was also possible to directly call the passed function without the need of the intermediate `onSubmit` like this `<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit(value)}>`

Answer (score 0):

Since Svelte 3, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61569655/9157799) pass down the parent method directly to the child component just like in React. From [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/e9zqn1/comment/fb2b6ih/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> There is no significant difference between callback props and events. The only difference is semantic. **Callback props used to be quite tricky to use in svelte 2** so events used to be the preferred method. **The redesign in v3 made callback props much simpler to use but we also still have events. So having both is partly historic.** Events are a little bit easier to forward up the tree but this is a pretty minor benefit, if at all.